# Honeywell Captuvo IOS Develop

Tags: ios

I am looking for help in integrating Captuvo SL22 SDK within appcelerator. The Captuvo SDK comes with the Captuvo scanner/msr for ipod. I am trying to use Captuvo SDK in a custom module and call it in the main app. I am able to establish a connection with the Captuvo Device by using the following code in the custom module startDecoder method:

```
- (IBAction)startDecoder:(id)sender {

ProtocolConnectionStatus state=  [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];

NSString *mess=nil;



switch (state) {
    case ProtocolConnectionStatusAlreadyConnected:
        mess=@"already connected";
        break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnect:
        mess=@"error connecting";
        break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusConnected:
        mess=@"connecting";
        break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnectIncompatiableSledFirmware:
        mess=@"incompatible firmware";
        break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusBatteryDepleted:
        mess=@"battery depleted";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
{UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:mess
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];}}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


[[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] addCaptuvoDelegate:self];}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}

return self;}
```

Device respond me connected no error, then I use below method to turn on the scanner:

```
- (IBAction)scanningBtn:(id)sender {

[[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderScanning];}
```

Unfortunately nothing happen, I'm trying to press side button, also nothing happen...

IOS version 7.1.2
Xcode version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In your ViewController.h :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CaptuvoEventsProtocol>
```

In your ViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] addCaptuvoDelegate:self];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];
}

- (void)decoderReady
{
    // called when scanner is ready (might take a second)
}

- (void)decoderDataReceived:(NSString *)barcode
{
    // called when you press the side button and a barcode was scanned
}
```

In your info.plist add this key and array :

```
...
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
      <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string>
    </array>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Integrate scanner and MSR of Honeywell SLed's function into your application; please read the CaptuvoSDK quick start and Release Note.

And the CaptuvoSDK also has the simple code in this zip package.